# What led Hausdorff to consider the possibility of "unerreichbar" or "weakly inaccessible" cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, math-history, large-cardinals

I would like to know how it was that Felix Hausdorff came to consider the possibility of, if not indeed necessity of, what he was the first to call "unerreichbare" or "unreachable" cardinals, or what we call, somewhat less clearly, "[weakly] inaccessible cardinals" today. To me such a move clearly constitutes a huge leap of imagination, much like the earlier one Cantor made when he proved that not all infinite sets have the same size. [even if that should have been clear already from the elementary proof that there can be no bijection between ANY set and its powerset] I suspect there was something in Hausdorff's very rich research project, mostly on the ordinals at the time, that "compelled" him to hypothesize such, to his day, very "large" cardinals; indeed cardinals much larger than, and "unreachable" from, the entire series of Beth cardinals, [at least from Beth1 to Bethω as were already known at the time]? ... I also haven't yet found much written about what the reception of Hausdorff's unreachable cardinals was by his contemporaries. I assume many of the latter must have thought the notion completely preposterous, but even that I haven't been able to confirm.  Any direction anyone can provide to me about such things will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "much larger than, and "unreachable" from, the entire series of Beth cardinals, [at least from Beth1 to Bethω as were already known at the time]" This isn't right: it's consistent that $\beth_1$ is already weakly inaccessible (assuming that weakly inaccessible cardinals are consistent in the first place of course). A **strongly** inaccessible cardinal must be a $\beth$-fixed point, but that's a different deal.

Comment: If you're writing a book about such concepts as successor cardinals and limit cardinals, regular and singular cardinals, it's hard for me to imagine how you could possibly ***avoid*** the question, can there be regular limit cardinals?

Comment: Just as a side remark, this question could benefit from some paragraph breaks.

Comment: I'll take the bait: what is "somewhat less clear" about "inaccessible" vs "unreachable"?

Comment: I am hardly trying to bait anyone, Alex, just pointing out that I prefer the original German term "unerreichbar," or "unreachable" in English, to "inaccessible," and I prefer the former terms because the paradigm case of the concept occurs already between the finite N and the infinite ω. I've always pictured the finites, and their successive power sets climbing ever "higher" but running into a barrier or ceiling at ω. The word "inaccessible" doesn't immediately connote a linear ordering of cardinals is possible.

Answer (score 9):

As bof said, I think the notion is actually natural enough that it would be weird to *not* ask about it. But in fact there is a good reason for Hausdorff to explicitly consider it.

The big question in set theory at the time was of course the continuum hypothesis. In $1904$, Konig had proved an interesting technical result about the continuum, namely $$cf(2^\omega)>\omega$$

(actually he proved [something more general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory))). Indeed this was the *only* nontrivial result about the continuum's cardinality known when Hausdorff wrote [his book in $1908$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal#CITEREFHausdorff1908), and as Cohen would observe later the only nontrivial result provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ at all. Moreover, Hausdorff had a role in this result: it was extracted from a failed argument against $\mathsf{CH}$ put forth by Konig, whose error was detected by Hausdorff (and independently Konig himself). See [here](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Eroquesol/History_of_Continuum.pdf) for more on this.

So by the time Hausdorff is writing in $1908$, there's already a known connection between the biggest question around and the notion of cofinality, and Hausdorff himself has been involved in forming this connection. Understanding the role of cofinality in cardinal arithmetic is therefore a very natural topic for him to think about, and among the first questions which arise is: "Are the uncountable *regular* cardinals exactly the uncountable *successor* cardinals?" So right there the notion of weak inaccessibility emerges naturally.

(That said I don't know of a source which definitely says that this is why Hausdorff introduced them. But it was definitely "in the air" at the time.)

---

It's also worth noting that a certain amount of the idea "weakly inaccessible cardinals are really big" took a while to become clear. Specifically, slogans like

> weakly inaccessible cardinals are so big we can't prove they exist

are rather common, even if they're fairly misleading (e.g. since we can have $2^\omega$ be weakly inaccessible if weakly inaccessibles are consistent in the first place). Now remember that the idea behind such slogan comes from combining two theorems of Godel, and one communal agreement:

1. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ captures "what we can prove about set theory."
2. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ cannot prove that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a model (let alone a *transitive* model!) unless $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is inconsistent.
3. If $\alpha$ is weakly inaccessible, then $L_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$.

But $\mathsf{ZFC}$ wouldn't even be introduced (let alone essentially universally accepted) in its modern formulation until the late $20$s, while Godel wouldn't prove $(2)$ and $(3)$ until the early $30$s and $50$s respectively.

- OK fine, we can easily sidestep $(2)$ above: it would be enough to show instead that $L_\alpha\models$ "There are no weakly inaccessible cardinals" if $\alpha$ is the least weakly inaccessible cardinal, which follows immediately from the appropriate *absoluteness* of weak inaccessibility. But as far as I'm aware of, even though it's easier that sort of argument post-dated the second incompleteness theorem, so the point about historicity still stands. *EDIT: it turns out that my history is a bit off; absoluteness proofs that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't prove the existence of a **strongly** inaccessible cardinal were [given in the $20$s](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29302/reasons-to-believe-vopenkas-principle-huge-cardinals-are-consistent/29310#comment64308_29318). Still, this significantly postdates Hausdorff's work.*

And finally, observe that point $(3)$ is actually surprisingly subtle. For **strong** inaccessibility things are very simple: it's almost trivial to show $V_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ whenever $\alpha$ is strongly inaccessible. So as soon as we think about absoluteness, or learn the second incompleteness theorem, it's obvious that strongly inaccessible cardinals reach beyond $\mathsf{ZFC}$. However, this argument breaks down for weak inaccessibility: it need **not** be the case that $V_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ if $\alpha$ is weakly inaccessible, and in fact - as noted above - it's possible that $2^\omega$ itself is weakly inaccessible. Instead, some genuine work is needed here: I don't offhand see a way to show that weakly inaccessible cardinals imply the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without developing the basic theory of [$L$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), which is highly nontrivial.

So our modern understanding of the logical strength of weak inaccessibility wasn't available to Hausdorff in $1908$. Of course it's clear from the definition that weakly inaccessible cardinals are pretty big, but there isn't that much evidence *at the time* that they're particularly special. So I suspect that their reception was much more muted than a reader brought up on the *modern* story of large cardinals might expect.

Comment: Though it is correct that the “unprovability” criterion for largeness is new, even Hausdorff considered weakly inaccessibles to be very large. Though I do not have a copy of the _Grunzüge der Mengenlehre_ there is a quote in the first chapter of Kanamori. Hausdorff writes (p. 131 of the GdM) that the least weakly inaccessible must have an “exorbitant magnitude.”

Comment: Thanks so much for that wonderful answer, Noah! It sounds to me like Konig's early result of 1904 probably did operate as a motivation to Hausdorff to consider the weakly inaccessible cardinals. If so, I am a bit surprised that no one had made the move before Hausdorff so perhaps there was some kind of psychological resistance among his contemporaries to accepting the new concept, as I assumed. I will have to delve more deeply into the state of the art in set theory in Hausdorff's time to answer that however.

Comment: @WdFusroy "I am a bit surprised that no one had made the move before Hausdorff" I mean, Hausdorff's book came out in 1908, just four years later. There wasn't much of a gap.